# Is it safe to upgrade kernel manually on a system which is using NVIDIA drivers?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, nvidia

Upgrading kernel manually on Ubuntu 14.04 can cause trouble with NVIDIA drivers? (one of the troubles could be booting to black screen)

I had lot of trouble with installing NVIDIA graphics drivers and getting it work, I had to reinstall my Ubuntu 14.04 four times.

Few reasons were installing nvidia*.run file and booting to black screen, or installing Intel Graphics for Linux and booting to black screen etc. I am tired of solving those problems.

I am want to know if there could be any problem before upgrading Linux kernel. Any advice would help

Comment: Unfortunately it is always possible for things to go wrong. Can you give more details about what you want to do?

Comment: @FaheemMitha upgrade linux kernel to latest one 3.19

Comment: Well, as long as you use the same Nvidia version for each kernel, you can keep all your drivers available for both kernels simultaneously, so you can always switch back if you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not always, newer versions of kernel may not be able to build DKMS modules with nvidia because of which nvidia drivers may not work when booted with that kernel.
As of 25 April 2015 I tried to install Linux kernel v4 which failed to work with nvidia so I had to remove it.